# Are ints promoted to long long when multiplied

Tags: c, integer-promotion

In the following code, is product guaranteed to contain a correct answer:

```
int num=INT_MAX, num2=INT_MAX;
long long product = num1 * num2;
```

Comment: No, you must cast one of the multipliers. `long long product = (long long)num1 * num2;`

Comment: There are only `int` values involved in the multiplication. Why should there be any type promotion? The assignement of the result only happens after the calculation is done.

Comment: the rule is that ~everything is promoted to int; or an integer type of greater rank if not all values of both operand types can be represented in a int...

Comment: You will want to look at [C11 Standard - 6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.1.1) and see *Note 58*.

Comment: @Gerhardh the problem is that multiplying 2 n-bit numbers produce a 2n-bit number, so what the OP asked is valid

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc yes, but an overflow alone is no trigger for some type propagation.